# Navigation Drawer not occupying the entire screen height

Tags: android, android-view, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a drawer layout with drawer on left.

Drawer has a button on click of which I want to replace the view of the drawer with a new view. **The problem is , when new view gets replaced it doesn’t occupy the entire screen height.**

To illustrate I have given a background colour to my navigation drawer views.

I want the Green view to occupy the entire screen height. Copy-paste the code below to get going:
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LayoutInflater inflater;
DrawerLayout drawer;
RelativeLayout parentRL;
RelativeLayout viewToBeRemovedRL;
View viewToBeAdded;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    parentRL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentRL);
    viewToBeRemovedRL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewToBeReplaced);
}

public void onRemoveView(View view) {
    viewToBeAdded = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_view, null);
    viewToBeRemovedRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    parentRL.addView(viewToBeAdded);
}

public void onOpenDrawer(View view) {
    drawer.openDrawer(parentRL);
}
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:onClick="onOpenDrawer"
        android:text="Open Drawer" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentRL"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewToBeReplaced"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:onClick="onRemoveView"
            android:text="Change View" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**add_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="290dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00FF00" >

<TextView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:text="New view"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try out by setting the width of your `add_view` layout fill_parent `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: my question has nothing to do with width, just the height.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when this happens, the drawer actually DOES occupy the entire screen height, it's just that the default background colour of the view is clear.

Set you RelativeLayout@id/parentRL 's background to a solid colour or some drawable, e.g.

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

and your drawer should cover the entire screen height.